# Uninstall yesterday's synaptic packages with virtual terminal on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, synaptic

How to uninstall packages that were installed on 10 May 2014, using only a virtual terminal?

Available are virtual terminals, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or +<kbd>F2</kbd>. Going back to the screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is possible. The package names are unknown.

---

Background: Only routine jobs were done on an updated install (that was upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 earlier).

At the end of the session the latest packages were installed with synaptic. The icon panel, terminal and top panel are missing after starting Ubuntu. The settings are visible with right click on the desktop and were not altered. Resolution of the monitors is OK. The screens are empty save for the (default) background image.

Xylo answered this question.

However, when trying Xylo's answer, I tried something else too:

From Ctrl-Alt-F1: sudo startx, goes back to empty screen and a terminal is available. So I did sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz  and setsid unity. this gives a side panel with icons but no top panel and a lot of warnings.

The question is now: how to get the top panel back and make both panel persist?
Correction: the question is now; My password is not accepted anymore, what to do; password was changed succesfully, but login returns the login screen; I will write a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see what was made that day, go to file **history.log** located in **/var/log/apt**.
You can use sed command:

```
sed -n -e '/Start-Date: 2014-05-10/,/End-Date: 2014-05-10/ p' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

In that way you can find packages names. Or put that output to a file:

```
sed -n -e '/Start-Date: 2014-05-10/,/End-Date: 2014-05-10/ p' /var/log/apt/history.log > filename.txt
```

Comment: cd /var/log/apt/history.log and cd ~/var/log/apt/history.log do not exist.

Comment: cd /var/log/apt is a path to file history.log do not type cd /var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: Of course, sorry about that. I edited my question.  (I wrote that before in the comment, but all edits are removed when one edits for longer than 5 minutes.)